# title of view posted link is not showing

Tags: 7

I have created a view with display format Unformatted List of titles (linked) and it works fine as it shows the list of linked title but the problem is now when I click the link to view the article it shows full post without title.

So am I doing something wrong? How to show the title there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem is with the node display itself and not the view.

When you click the title you're led to the node page.

Check your content type display settings in **Structure->Content Type->(your content)->Manage Display**

Comment: I'm using content type -- article, how should I do? thanks.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: zen subtheme zenophile

Comment: Does zenophile copy over tpl.php files? Could you check the node.tpl.php?

The zen templates themselves are here:
sites\all\themes\zen\templates

Comment: yes there is node.tpl.php, and I removed the if condition and works fine, but confused that is good way?

Comment: I just removed this: `<?php if (!$page && $title): ?>`

Comment: please check the node.tpl.php in your generated zenophile theme and compare it to the node.tpl.php in zen. `sites\all\themes\zen\templates\node.tpl.php` to your `sites\all\themes\themename\templates\node.tpl.php`

Comment: There should be a line like this ` <?php if (!$page && $title): ?>
        <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
      <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: yeah! I already commented out that but is good way to do ?

Comment: If the line is there then leave it in. Did you add any css that may have affected the page title? `h1` or `.title`?

Comment: No, I didn't, and I inspected but there's no title.